# How to style React rendering compoents

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
<div>
                    <h3>{this.props.product.name}</h3>
                    <h3>{this.props.product.code}</h3>

                   {this.renderColors()}
                    <article>
                      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup(this.props.product.description)} />
                    </article>
                  </div>
```

This is react rendering objects and I want to Style it using CSS. Is there a way to do it? I have a seperate css file for this html file.

Comment: Since you haven't mention whether you have created separate modules/ components for the necessary elements, please check this excellent article. https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-3-react/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it two ways:

1. Use inline styling
2. Use external CSS

**Using inline styling**

Injecting the style object

```
const style = {
  color: "blue"
}

<div style={style}></div>
```

Or applying it inline directly

```
<div style={{"color": "blue"}}></div>
```

**Using external CSS**

in your CSS

```
.blue {
  color: blue;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

in your component

```
<div className="blue"></div>
<div id="red"></div>
```

Comment: I tried the external CSS way, but it doesn't apply.

Comment: How are you bundling your CSS modules? Webpack? Browserfiy?

Comment: I use Webpack here.

Comment: Do you mind updating your question to include your webpack config? That should help